# Catching Fatal Error in Node.js | FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, md5

I wanted to know if there was a way to catch this error:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

I have tried:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){
        //do something
 })
```

But this did not catch the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

P.S This is happening when generating MD5 hashes for a string of about eighteen files and I am using the md5 module like this:

```
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    fs.readFile(array[i], function(err,buf){
        console.log(mdf(buf))
    })

}
```

Comment: Did you find a way to handle this?

Comment: @Aashish check out the accepted answer

Comment: This doesn't answer "how to catch exception"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid buffering entire files in memory. Calculate the md5 hash a chunk at a time instead. Example:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    crypto = require('crypto');

var array = [ 'foo.txt' ];

array.forEach(function(filename) {
  var hasher = crypto.createHash('md5', { encoding: 'hex' });
  fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(hasher).on('finish', function() {
    process.nextTick(function() {
      var md5sum = hasher.read();
      console.log(filename + ': ' + md5sum);
    });
  });
});
```